# <Part> cannot be resolved to a type (Yes, I have imported List and ArrayList)

Tags: java, eclipse, arraylist, javafx, compiler-errors

sorry to bother the good people with another "cannot be resolved to a type", but I'm pretty stumped. I'm programming in java and like I said, I checked my imports and I checked my Part class, but my limited knowledge of programming appears to be showing.
Please help me to identify the cause of the errors.

Under the problems tab, I have two issues,

ArrayList cannot be resolved to a type
Parts cannot be resolved to type

I imagine that last one causes the first one.

My compiler gives me

> Caused by: java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problems: 
>       ArrayList cannot be resolved to a type
>       Parts cannot be resolved to a type at PartsBox.View.PartsBoxButtonHandlers.addImportFile_handler(PartsBoxButtonHandlers.java:51)
>       ... 62 more

The region toward the bottom that has comment tags is where eclipse tells me that I've done something wrong.

```
package PartsBox.View;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.TableView;
import javafx.stage.FileChooser;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class PartsBoxButtonHandlers {

List<String> headerItems;
List<ArrayList<String>> itemTable;
List<Part> parts;

@FXML
private Button addImportFile_button;
@FXML
private Button saveLib_button;
@FXML
private Button addManual_button;
@FXML
private Button clearTable_button;
@FXML
private Button exportMissing_button;
@FXML
private Button exportBOM_button;
@FXML
private Button clearBOM_button;
@FXML
private TableView<Part> libraryTable;



public void addImportFile_handler(){

    FileChooser chooser = new FileChooser();
    chooser.setTitle("Open Files");
    List<File> files = chooser.showOpenMultipleDialog(new Stage());

    // ----------------------------------------

        parts = new ArrayList<Parts>();

    // ----------------------------------------
```

This is the Part class

```
package PartsBox.View;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Part {

private ArrayList<String> part;

public Part(int headerSize){
    part = new ArrayList<String>();
    for(int j = 0 ; j < headerSize; j++){
        part.add("");
         }
     }

     public ArrayList<String> getPartListArray(){
         return part;
     }

     public void appendHeaderSpace(){
        part.add("");
     }
     public void insertPartDetail(String s, int n){
        part.set(n, s);
     }

}
```

Comment: The JDK is not properly configured in your Eclipse configuration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You class name is `Part` and not `Parts`.

So here change it to `Part`.

```
 part = new ArrayList<Part>();
```

Also you declared the ArrayList as `part` and not `parts`. Change that accordingly as well.

Comment: Thanks, it is late and I am tired. Probably should have waited to post it tomorrow. What a silly mistake

Answer (score 1):

Remove the (s) from class name Part. Should say

```
parts = new ArrayList<Part>();
```

not

```
parts = new ArrayList<Parts>();
```

If you use an IDE, it would help you.

Comment: Ok, now you changed.

Comment: I didnt change anything , just formatted it since I am new to stackoverflow and wanted proper indentation :)

Comment: See the edit list and you will be able to see the first answer that you posted.

Comment: This was your first answer : Remove the plural from Part. Should say

parts = new ArrayList();

not

parts = new ArrayList();

Comment: This is because I did not format my code within the code tags and stuff between < and > got removed